# How to split a python list of lists into 3 separate lists according to their value in the each sublist's first entry?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How do you use Python to accomplish the following:

I have the following list

```
StateCityList = [["Kansas","Overland Park"],
                 ["Kansas","Lenexa"],
                 ["Kansas","Olathe"],
                 ["Missouri","Kansas City"],
                 ["Missouri","Raytown"],
                 ["Missouri","Independence"],
                 ["Texas","Dallas"],
                 ["Texas","Houston"],
                 ["Texas","San Antonio"]]
```

I want to get all the cities in a certain state into a separate list like this

```
   Kansas =[["Kansas","Overland Park],    
            ["Kansas","Lenexa"],
            ["Kansas","Olathe"]]

Missouri =  [["Missouri","Kansas City"]
             ["Missouri","Raytown"]
             ["Missouri","Independence"]]

Texas =  [["Texas","Dallas"]
          ["Texas","Houston"]
          ["Texas","San Antonio"]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not use dictionary?

Comment: By the way, the number of cities varies and I never know for sure. I have to query all cities in a given state somehow from a long list of 1000+ cities that I get.

Comment: Don't you have to have unique keys for dictionaries? I have several cities for the same states (keys)

Comment: If you have the cities in a list, then there will be only one key for each State :-) see answers below for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat more beginner-friendly code. I like the one above though.

```
StateCityList = [["Kansas","Overland Park"],
                 ["Kansas","Lenexa"],
                 ["Kansas","Olathe"],
                 ["Missouri","Kansas City"],
                 ["Missouri","Raytown"],
                 ["Missouri","Independence"],
                 ["Texas","Dallas"],
                 ["Texas","Houston"],
                 ["Texas","San Antonio"]]



sc = {}
for state, city in StateCityList:
    if state in sc:
        sc[state].append((state,city))
    else:
        sc[state] = [(state, city)]

# print
for state in sc:
    print(state, sc[state])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(StateCityList, key=itemgetter(0))}

{'Kansas': [['Kansas', 'Overland Park'],
            ['Kansas', 'Lenexa'],
            ['Kansas', 'Olathe']],
 'Missouri': [['Missouri', 'Kansas City'],
              ['Missouri', 'Raytown'],
              ['Missouri', 'Independence']],
 'Texas': [['Texas', 'Dallas'], 
           ['Texas', 'Houston'], 
           ['Texas', 'San Antonio']]}
```

**NOTE:**
If StateCityList is not sorted by state name, then use this:

```
{k: list(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(StateCityList, key=itemgetter(0)), itemgetter(0))}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `setdefault`:

```py
StateCityDict = {}
for state, city in StateCityList:
    StateCityDict.setdefault(state, []).append([state, city])
```

Answer (score 0):

**solution using set**

You don't need to import any packages to perform this task as you can identify the list of unique States using [**set**](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/set.html), :

```
# find unique set of states using "set"
states=set([k[0] for k in StateCityList])

# build dictionary splitting by city:
res={}
for s in states:
    res[s]=[k for k in StateCityList if k[0]==s]
```

giving the resulting dictionary:

```
{'Missouri': [['Missouri', 'Kansas City'], ['Missouri', 'Raytown'], ['Missouri', 'Independence']], 'Texas': [['Texas', 'Dallas'], ['Texas', 'Houston'], ['Texas', 'San Antonio']], 'Kansas': [['Kansas', 'Overland Park'], ['Kansas', 'Lenexa'], ['Kansas', 'Olathe']]}
```

**nicer output: Avoid duplication of State information in result**

This answers the question as you set it, but do you really need to repeat the State within the resulting list? I think it is neater to leave it out in this way:

```
res={}
for s in set([k[0] for k in StateCityList]):
    res[s]=[c for k,c in StateCityList if k==s]
```

Which gives a neater dictionary, with the key=State and the entry a list of the cities:

```
{'Missouri': ['Kansas City', 'Raytown', 'Independence'], 
 'Texas': ['Dallas', 'Houston', 'San Antonio'], 
  'Kansas': ['Overland Park', 'Lenexa', 'Olathe']}
```

**alternative using zip**

I haven't tested it but suspect it is faster for large datasets if you substitute the first iterator for the zip command, although I prefer the iterator in most circumstances as I find the code clearer and easier to understand:

```
res={}  
for s in set(list(zip(*StateCityList))[0]):
    res[s]=[k for k in StateCityList if k[0]==s]
```